# Android SDK Kali 2.0

Tags: android, kali-linux

I'm trying to install android sdk on kali 2.0, when i tried to run android.sh file in dir:android-sdk-linux>tools, it opens the file in text editor, tried the "chmod 771" command but it doest worked at all, what should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

here is what i found:
i simply went to the dir through terminal and used the command "chmod +x android" and then i entered "sh android"
that has done the job for me....